# Is it possible to define a record as the union of 2 records

Tags: oracle

```
declare
     type a is record(a1 number, a2 varchar2(10));
     type b is record(b1 number, b2 varchar2(10));
     type c is record(a1 number, b2 varchar2(10),c1 number, c2 varchar2(10));
begin
    null;
end;
```

the record c is defined like that: the fields of c are the field of a + b.

I have a real example with a lot of field. Is there a more efficient way to declare c.

Something like that ?

```
 type c is record( a..., c...);
```

And more importantly I would like thatif I change the definition of a or b, the definition of c change too.
[code on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BArYilI1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%ROWTYPE only applies to tables.  Just do this:

declare
     type a is record(a1 number, a2 varchar2(10));
     type b is record(b1 number, b2 varchar2(10));
     type c is record(a2 a, b2 b);
begin
    null;
end;
```

Yes if you change a or b, then c will change

Comment: This is not quite the same as the OP trying to apply the spread operator as the OP is trying to get a record with attributes `c.a1`, `c.a2`, `c.b1` and `c.b2` but yours would give nested attributes `c.a2.a1`, `c.a2.a2`, `c.b2.b1` and `c.b2.b2`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to define a record as the union of 2 records?

No, Oracle does not support:

- the `...` spread operator so `type c is record( a..., c...)` is invalid syntax.
- the `%ROWTYPE` attribute on records.

---

You either need to:

- manually list all the attributes:

  ```sql
  type c is record(a1 number, a2 varchar2(10), b1 number, b2 varchar2(10));
  ```

  and then update the record whenever types `a` or `b` change.
- use nested records:

  ```sql
  type c is record(x a, y b);
  v_c c;
  ```

  but then you have to address the types as `v_c.x.a1` or `v_c.y.b2` and cannot use `v_c.a1` or `v_c.b2` as you are not directly declaring the attributes in type `c`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    type a is record(a1 number := 1, a2 varchar2(10) := 'd');
    var_a a;
    type b is record(b1 number := 1, b2 varchar2(10) := 't');
    var_b b;
    type c is record(a1 number := var_a.a1, a2 varchar2(10) := var_a.a2, b1 number := var_b.b1, b2 varchar2(10) := var_b.b2);
    var_c c;
Begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record A = ' || To_Char(var_a.a1) || ', ' || var_a.a2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record B = ' || To_Char(var_b.b1) || ', ' || var_b.b2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record C = ' || To_Char(var_c.a1) || ', ' || var_c.a2 || ', ' || To_Char(var_c.b1) || ', ' || var_c.b2);
End;

/*  R e s u l t :
anonymous block completed
Record A = 1, d
Record B = 1, t
Record C = 1, d, 1, t
*/
```